# frames - I see that frames are not supported in HTML5 - does that mean not supported if the DOCTYPE specifies HTML5?

Tags: html, doctype, frames

I have read that frames are not supported in HTML5 but I still want to use them, on occasion.

:-) before you launch into a lecture as to the "evils" of frames, let me say I've resolved the biggest ones - orphaned frames and useless bookmarks. My pages which use frames check to see if they are in the correct frameset, if not, they load the correct frameset. When you bookmark one of my pages which contain frames, the bookmark takes you to the "page" you bookmarked, not just the frameset with default frame sources.

As to HTML5 not supporting frames, is using them a matter of specifying the correct DOCTYPE so that the page is not considered HTML5?

I admit I know very little about DOCTYPE statements and would appreciate any knowledge you can share with me.

Bob

Answer (score 3):

Browsers either support frames or they don't. "Out of the box", all the modern graphical browsers do, though it may be possible for users to disable them. The doctype makes no difference to this.

In HTML5, frames are **obsolete**. This means that authors, if they want their pages to be HTML5 compliant, must not use frames. It does not mean the user agents (e.g. browsers) should not support them.¹ Indeed, the [HTML5 spec devotes a section here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets) and [another one here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#frameset) to describing how user agents should process frames and framesets.

<sub>¹ So to be absolutely clear, the statement "frames are not supported in HTML5" is simply inaccurate.</sub>